# TYPO3 template extension- not able to change Mask back-end configuration and Page Tree not properly imported

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, tx-mask

I have created a TYPO3 template extension using the following method:
1.1 via Extension Manager
Open the module "Extension" in the TYPO3 Backend and search for the mask Extension.
Click on the configure icon at the end of the row.
Now you should be able to change the settings.

Changes are stored in typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php.

*Facing the following problems:*

1.We created the folder/extension as mentioned. While installing this extension we have to change Mask back-end configuration. This is not working.

2.Page tree contents are not properly imported i.e. all page contents are missing.

Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you want to use Mask? First question: the extension is enabled? (green "cube"icon) in Extension Manager

Comment: Hi Ricardo  Thanks for your response. I shall check and let you know.

Comment: Hi Ricardo , Yes mask extension is enabled. I guess we have not explained the problem well. We have created a template extension. After installation, the Mask is not working. I have uploaded the extension here: We have uploaded the extension here typo3sample06.softsolutions4u.com/user_ss4u.zip.

Comment: you should provide better description (or links) for the tutorials you use, otherwise your mentioning of step 1.1 is fruitless. your description att all is very confusing and not specific. also creating (at least) three questions with the same content does not make it any clearer.

Comment: Thanks Bernd. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As Bernd wrote in the answer below, make sure that the TypoScript template of MASK is loaded (i.e. go in Template > Edit whole template record > tab "includes" > "Include static (from extensions)"

Comment: Thanks so much Riccardo!

Answer (score 1):

We have a working configuration where we stored the full mask-configuration as part of our site-extension.

As designed you need to configure mask before you start to define any CEs, so that all CE definitions are stored in the correct folders.

**For the rendering you also need to include the static template of `ext:mask`.**

Our configuration is:
[image: Mask config part 1]
[image: Mask config part 2]
[image: Mask config part 3]

This configuration is stored in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` as there goes every configuration done in the extension manager.

Comment: Awesome Bernd. Thanks so much!!